# How do I implement EDSDK's EdsSetProgressCallback function properly?

Tags: sdk, progress, edsdk

I'm trying to use `EdsSetProgressCallback` function from Canon EDSDK 2.10 to inform user about image saving completion. I've set `inProgressOption` parameter to `kEdsProgressOption_Done`. The problem is, that after successful saving no action is performed. Can you tell me whether I'm implementing this function correctly?

My callback function:

```
EdsError EDSCALLBACK CManEosDlg::ProgressFunc (EdsUInt32 inPercent, EdsVoid* inContext, EdsBool* outCancel) {
    CManEosDlg *pobj = (CManEosDlg *)inContext;
    CStatic *pProgress=(CStatic*)pobj->GetDlgItem(IDC_LABEL);
    pProgress->SetWindowText("Image saved");
    return EDS_ERR_OK;
}
```

Fragment od image saving function:

```
EdsStreamRef        DstStreamRef;
EdsError err = EdsCreateFileStream( path , kEdsFileCreateDisposition_CreateAlways , kEdsAccess_Write , &DstStreamRef );
if( err == EDS_ERR_OK ) {
    err = EdsSetProgressCallback(DstStreamRef, ProgressFunc, kEdsProgressOption_Done, this);
    if(err == EDS_ERR_OK) {
        err = EdsSaveImage(_imageModel->getImageObject(), inImageType , inSaveSetting , DstStreamRef ); 
    }
}
EdsRelease(DstStreamRef);
```

Latter returns EDS_ERR_OK from `EdsSetProgressCallback` but `ProgressFunc` is never called after image is saved. I've checked it by putting messagebox there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be nice!

Instead of `EdsSaveImage` try `EdsDownload`.
I think EdsSaveImage won't send a call for the callback function.

BTW I was wondering, that you got the "Callbacker" working within your namespace:

```
EdsError EDSCALLBACK CManEosDlg::ProgressFunc
```

In my project i had to define that without namespace in the top of my "CManEosDlg"-class, as

```
EdsError EDSCALLBACK ProgressFunc
```